# How to add a package-specific index-url to requirements.txt?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I want to add a package to my `requirements.txt` that would correspond to the command line

```
pip3 install foo --index-url https://foo.com/bar/baz
```

I *appended*

```
--index-url https://foo.com/bar/baz
foo
```

to the *end* of `requirements.txt` in the hope that the `index-url` option will affect only things that come after it. It seems to work (at least as long as I am on the VPN from which `foo.com` is visible).

Is this the right approach?
Thanks.

Comment: The `pip install -r requirements.txt` is effectively the same as doing `cat requirements.txt | xargs pip install`, so in your case the custom index arg will be applied to all packages.

Comment: Probably more like `grep -v '^#' requirements.txt | xargs pip install` but I see your point. Thanks. Do you know how people handle the issue of requirements coming from different sources?

Comment: I'd say it depends on your use case. If your use case is _download selection of dependencies from private index, rest from PyPI_ because private deps are not uploaded to PyPI, replace `--index-url` with `--extra-index-url` so `pip` first tries to download from PyPI and resorts to private index on failures.

Comment: If your use case is e.g. _prevent pip from downloading packages from PyPI to protect against package spoofing_, then you won't be able to solve it locally via flags and need to configure the private index accordingly. I would e.g. recommend `devpi` as it has package spoofing prevention turned on by default and point `--index-url` to your private index, so it can decide itself whether to proxy the download requests to PyPI.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The arguments in `requirements.txt` are applied to all packages; the command

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

with `requirements.txt` being

```
foo
bar>1
baz==2
--flag
```

is effectively the same as running

```
$ pip install "foo" "bar>1" "baz==2" --flag
```

If you want to download only a selection of dependencies from your private index, use `--extra-index-url` instead of `--index-url`. This will instruct `pip` to download packages from PyPI if available, and resort to your private index otherwise (multiple `--extra-index-url`s are supported, too).

To handle the vice versa - download from private index if available, fallback to PyPI - set your private index as primary, PyPI as extra index:

```
--index-url=https://my.index/ --extra-index-url=https://pypi.org/simple
```

If you have other use cases, for example protection against package spoofing, this can't be effectively solved with `pip`. There are, however, index servers like `devpi` that can proxy download requests to PyPI and offer spoofing protection out of the box.

Edit: [@Geordie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796634/geordie) explained package spoofing in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043452/how-to-add-a-package-specific-index-url-to-requirements-txt/57060441#comment104827048_57060441) well.

Comment: Looks like you can also use the --no-index flag for even more control:
--no-index
--find-links /my/local/archives
--find-links http://some.archives.com/archives

Comment: Also be aware that pip still tries to source the latest version of the module if you don't specify it in requirements.txt.  So even though you set your primary index to myIndex and extra to pypi, if pypi contains a higher version of the same library than myIndex it will still pull the package from pypi

Comment: Although it worked for me to get installed de dependencies applying `pip install -r requirements.txt` but still I was getting error when using _requirements.txt_ for declaring the dependencies of my package built by `setup.py`. Finally, I solved this issue introducing the corresponding url as `setup( ... dependency_links=[ "http://some.archives.com/archives" ], ...)` 
as described [here](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html)