# Deploying an app on Google App Engine - Error from requirements.txt

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I can't deploy an app on Google App Engine.

The problem seems to come from my `requirements.txt` file:

- When I deploy the example [building-an-app-1](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/standard_python37/building-an-app/building-an-app-1), it works well.
- When I replace the original `requirements.txt` file with mine, it doesn't work*.

Here is my `requirements.txt`:

```
Flask==1.1.1
flask-wtf==0.14.2
unidecode
numpy
openfoodfacts
os
```

When I remove the last 2 packages, it works.

What is the problem?

*`gcloud deploy app` returns:

```
File upload done.
Updating service [default]...failed.                                           
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [9] Cloud build 813ab290-60a1-427c-830f-3a7e2d35f39b status: FAILURE.
Build error details: {"error":{"errorType":"BuildError","canonicalCode":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","errorId":"288DA415","errorMessage":"01 Feb 2020 17:23:53 INFO     Arguments: ['--parser_script=/usr/local/bin/ftl.par', '--src=', '--entrypoint=', '--name=eu.gcr.io/skilful-alpha-259713/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:34df8d6c-74e5-4583-bd94-165295531608', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=eu.gcr.io/skilful-alpha-259713/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--builder-output-path=\"\"', '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--base=eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20191019_3_7_4_RC00']
01 Feb 2020 17:23:53 INFO     Unparsed arguments: ['--name=eu.gcr.io/skilful-alpha-259713/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:34df8d6c-74e5-4583-bd94-165295531608', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=eu.gcr.io/skilful-alpha-259713/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--builder-output-path=\"\"', '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--base=eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20191019_3_7_4_RC00']
01 Feb 2020 17:23:53 INFO     Executing ['/usr/local/bin/ftl.par', '--name=eu.gcr.io/skilful-alpha-259713/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:34df8d6c-74e5-4583-bd94-165295531608', '--directory=/workspace', '--destination=/srv', '--cache-repository=eu.gcr.io/skilful-alpha-259713/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d', '--cache', '--builder-output-path=\"\"', '--additional-directory=/.googleconfig', '--python-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7', '--pip-cmd=/env/bin/python3.7 -m pip', '--venv-cmd=/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env', '-v=DEBUG', '--base=eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20191019_3_7_4_RC00']
INFO     FTL version python-v0.17.0
INFO     Beginning FTL build for python
INFO     FTL arg passed: virtualenv_dir /env
INFO     FTL arg passed: ttl 168
INFO     FTL arg passed: python_cmd /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7
INFO     FTL arg passed: cache True
INFO     FTL arg passed: virtualenv_cmd virtualenv
INFO     FTL arg passed: entrypoint None
INFO     FTL arg passed: exposed_ports None
INFO     FTL arg passed: pip_cmd /env/bin/python3.7 -m pip
INFO     FTL arg passed: tar_base_image_path None
INFO     FTL arg passed: export_cache_stats False
INFO     FTL arg passed: builder_output_path \"\"
INFO     FTL arg passed: destination_path /srv
INFO     FTL arg passed: sh_c_prefix False
INFO     FTL arg passed: base eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20191019_3_7_4_RC00
INFO     FTL arg passed: cache_key_version v0.17.0
INFO     FTL arg passed: cache_salt 
INFO     FTL arg passed: cache_repository eu.gcr.io/skilful-alpha-259713/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d
INFO     FTL arg passed: venv_cmd /opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 -m venv /env
INFO     FTL arg passed: name eu.gcr.io/skilful-alpha-259713/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:34df8d6c-74e5-4583-bd94-165295531608
INFO     FTL arg passed: global_cache False
INFO     FTL arg passed: upload True
INFO     FTL arg passed: fail_on_error True
INFO     FTL arg passed: output_path None
INFO     FTL arg passed: directory /workspace
INFO     FTL arg passed: additional_directory /.googleconfig
INFO     FTL arg passed: verbosity DEBUG
INFO     starting: full build
INFO     starting: builder initialization
INFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'eu.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/python37:python37_20191019_3_7_4_RC00'
INFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'eu.gcr.io/skilful-alpha-259713/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:34df8d6c-74e5-4583-bd94-165295531608'
INFO     builder initialization took 0 seconds
INFO     starting: build process for FTL image
INFO     starting: checking_cached_interpreter_layer
INFO     starting: check python version
INFO     `python version` full cmd:
/opt/python3.7/bin/python3.7 --version
I.
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the error you are receiving Cloud Build is failing to install the last two dependencies that you are specifiying on your requirements.txt file. If you go to the [Cloud Build History page](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/view-build-results#viewing_build_results) and check your failed deployments you'll notice that the deployments are failing with a similar error message to this one:

```
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:
Step #1 - "builder":   Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openfoodfacts==0.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10)) (from versions: )
Step #1 - "builder": No matching distribution found for openfoodfacts==0.1.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 10))
```

There is no need to include the [os module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/os.html?highlight=os#module-os) on the requirements.txt since it is part of Python's 3.7 Standard Library. Notice for example that the [main.py](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard_python37/building-an-app/building-an-app-1/main.py) you are basing your application from makes an import of the [datetime module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#module-datetime) and this is not specified on the [requirements.txt file](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/standard_python37/building-an-app/building-an-app-1/requirements.txt).

The [Open Food Facts package](https://github.com/openfoodfacts/openfoodfacts-python) has not actually been released on PyPI (i.e., https://pypi.org/project/openfoodfacts/ is 404) so you'll need to refer to the relevant section of the [App Engine's documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies#private_dependencies) and add it manually, in a similar fashion to this:

1. Create a `lib` directory on your application's Project Directory (e.g. my using `mkdir lib`).
2. Copy the dependencies you need to the new created `lib` directory by issuing the following command: `pip3 install git+git://github.com/openfoodfacts/openfoodfacts-python.git -t lib`.
3. Go to the `lib` directory and verify that all dependencies have been installed correctly.
4. Modify your `requirements.txt` file to use the dependencies required by the Open Food Facts package. It should look like this:

```
Flask==1.1.1
flask-wtf==0.14.2
unidecode==1.1.1
numpy==1.18.1
certifi==2019.11.28
chardet==3.0.4
idna==2.8
requests==2.22.0
urllib3==1.25.8
```

5. Import the module in your app in a similar fashion to `import lib.openfoodfacts as openff`.
6. Use the `gcloud app deploy` command to deploy your application.

At the end you should have a project directory with a similar file structure than this one:

```
building-an-app-1/
    app.yaml
    lib/
        ...
        openfoodfacts/
            autosuggest.py
            facets.py
            __init__.py
            openbeautyfacts.py
            openpetfoodfacts.py
            products.py
            __pycache__/
            utils.py
        ...
    main.py
    requirements.txt
    static/
        script.js
        style.css
    templates/
        index.html
```

where you can import the `os` and `openfoodfacts` modules on the `main.py` file by using the following:

```
...
import datetime
import os
import lib.openfoodfacts as openff
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using this requirements.txt file locally like this?:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

It looks like the last two lines of your requirements.txt file do not correspond to Python packages that can be installed with pip.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the presence of both `os` and `openfoodfacts` in the `requirements.txt` file (which needs to contain only pip-installable packages, see [Declaring and managing dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies)) are causing pip install errors:

```
[venv] openfoodfacts> pip install os
Collecting os
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement os (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for os

[venv] openfoodfacts> pip install openfoodfacts
Collecting openfoodfacts
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement openfoodfacts (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for openfoodfacts
```

You shouldn't need to add `os` to your requirements, it is part of the standard python installation, you can just import it.

And `openfoodfacts` doesn't appear to be a regular `Pypi` package. If it's coming from a pip repository which doesn't require SSH keys you may be able to specify it in the `requirements.txt` file, see [How to add a package-specific index-url to requirements.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043452/how-to-add-a-package-specific-index-url-to-requirements-txt). Otherwise you need to install it in your app so that it can be uploaded together with your app code, check the [Private dependencies](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies#private_dependencies) section.

You can/should always try to [install your dependencies locally](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/specifying-dependencies#installing_dependencies_locally) as a sanity check for your `requirements.txt` file. Be mindful with pip repos requiring SSH keys as you may have those by default accessible via your account configs.