# pip installable package with alternative index in requirements.txt

Tags: python, pip, pytorch

Along the lines of [pip requirements.txt with alternative index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477117/pip-requirements-txt-with-alternative-index) (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57043452/how-to-add-a-package-specific-index-url-to-requirements-txt)) I have to install a version of a package that requires passing an `--extra-index-url` and I want to do this inside *requirements.txt*. This works if I run `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

The kicker is that I want my package to be pip installable. I have the `requirements.txt` of my package inside a directory with the other necessary files like *setup.py* and the *pyproject.toml* and whilst I can run the previous command I can't do `pip install .` to install my package locally from the current directory.

How can I ship a pip installable package with a requirements.txt file that contains an extra index URL?

(If pip doesn't allow this as I suspect, please suggest workarounds!)

Right now I have this in the requirements file (just an excerpt):

```
seaborn==0.11.2
--extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113 
torch==1.10.2+cu113 
pandas==1.1.5
numpy==1.17.4
```

My specific use case is with PyTorch, which I need to install with the correct CUDA version, so the command to install the relevant packages from [*PyTorch Start Locally*](https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/) is:

```sh
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
```

Comment: Docs for `requirements.txt`: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/requirements-file-format/#global-options

Comment: `pytorch` in `requirements.txt`: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bpytorch%5D+requirements.txt